# How do I install Torify on an M1 Mac?

Tags: homebrew, tor

Can someone explain how to download and install Torify for an M1 mac?  I've tried installing via Homebrew, and got the following errors:

```
Warning: No available formula with the name "torify". Did you mean trivy?
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
This similarly named formula was found:
trivy
To install it, run:
  brew install trivy
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

I'm on MacOS 12.3.1. I'm looking for this, becuase I want to use youtube-dl via Tor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I typed "torify" into my mac, I get this output:

```
The program 'torify' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
  brew install tor
```

From here, it is simple to figure out that `brew install tor` will install torify, but not `brew install torify`

Comment: @tomh I am not on am M1 mac, but you attempted to install 'torify' when you should install 'tor'. When i tried installing 'torify', it failed, but when i installed 'tor', torify started working. Also, my error occurred when I tried to RUN torify without it installed, pointing me to a package to download for torify.

Comment: Which tool do you have installed to propose packages in case a binary is missing?

Comment: @nohillside https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-command-not-found

Comment: Thanks!  Installing 'brew install tor' and then installing 'brew install torsocks' seems to have worked, but youtube-dl is giving an error for the file I need to download. Suspect I need to set the output node for Tor, but haven't worked out how to do that yet.